# databasegeneratedattribute replacement in .net 4 from .net 4.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have started working on MVC, entity framework and framework 4.5 project for my company. I have completed 30 to 40% of my project. But  i just came to know that our company uses windows server 2003. Where i can host only 4.0 version applications, not 4.5 ,Now i am thinking to downgrade my application to 4.0 But i am getting following error when i changed the target framework to 4.0 from 4.5
I did online search, but did not find any proper solution.

1. The type or namespace name 'Tableattribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2. The type or namespace name 'DatabaseGeneratedAttributeAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And few other. Please help me how to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using EF6 and .NET 4.5 the DataAnnotaions would work as expected as they were included in the framework 4.5. If you have to downgrade the app, then try doing one thing. Use EF5 assembly which contains the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema namespace which contains the Attributes you need